# Writing big number of entries in Cassandra db

Tags: cassandra, datastax

We have a temp table that stores a "big" number of records. Every record is a list of random integers that are generated "offline".

So in my pseudocode

```
typedef std::map<int, vector<int>> myMap; //datastructure
myMap rows = initialize(); //
```

the rows variable contains something like this:

```
1, <1,2,3,100,13> //random numbers
2, <4,5,2,123,33> //random numbers
3, <43,45,22,9,45> //random numbers
   ...
```

This list has 10 million entries.

My question: what is the best way to flush these data to my cassandra db? I have created a table in order to store the "rows" variable there. I guess that it is not optimal way to save these data to db without risking the integrity of the data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What are your concerns? If you are worried about "slow" loading then you can speed it up by feeding your data through [sstableloader](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/tools/toolsBulkloader_t.html). Or if you are too lazy just feed them one by one, possibly with async writes.